# ArrayList, private instance variable and constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, drjava

I'm having trouble with creating an `Arraylist` in a new class (I'm using the [DrJava](http://www.drjava.org/) IDE). The assignment is to create a constructor with `n` lottery tickets numbered from `1 to n`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tombola {
  
    private ArrayList<Integer> arr;
  
    public Tombola(int n){
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
            this.arr.add(i) = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

> unexpected type.
>
> required: variable.
>
> found: value.

I've tried to change `n` and `i` to integer, but it didn't help.

Comment: Don't assume that just because it has `Array` in the name that it is one. Arrays have built-in syntax to read and write to a certain index, whereas an `ArrayList` is a class like any other. You need to use a different method to read than to write, and there are several for each. `set()` and `add()` are the most notable, as well as `remove()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
 this.arr.add(i) = i + 1;
```

`add(...)` method does not provide you with a target for an assignment, so assigning it `i+1` would not work. Instead, you should add `i+1`, like this:

```
 this.arr.add(i + 1);
```

You have two additional errors in your code:

1: this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
```

will iterate `n-1` times, not `n` times. To get `n` iterations use

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // <<== This is most common
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) // <<== This is less common
```

2: your array list is not initialized. You need to change its declaration as follows:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

or even to

```
private List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```